# Reading csv file but with empty strings[]

Tags: java, csv

In the code below you can see how I'm reading a csv file. However, the `if(!splitter2[0].equals(""))` does not seem to work. In the last 3 lines of the file there are many semicolons (the delimiter of a csv is semicolon). However, somehow it is thinking that it's not empty. BTW, `.equals(";")` doesnt work neither. Anyway, it seems to go through this if statement as I still get the out of bound exception (deleting the semicolons will solve the exception and I've tried printing something outside the while loop and its not working with those lines)

> ***`;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;; 
>   ;;;`***

```
while((line2 = bra.readLine()) != null) {

    //splits the lines in the file
    String[] splitter2 = line2.split(tomtomkm.cvsSplitBy); 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("", tomtomkm.fileverschil), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

    //adding everything to lists
    if(!splitter2[0].equals("")) {
        dateList.add(splitter2[0]);
        licenseverschiList.add(splitter2[1]);
        firstnameList.add(splitter2[2]);
        lastnameList.add(splitter2[3]); 
        System.out.println(dateList.size() + " en " + licenseverschiList.size() + "en " + firstnameList.size() + " en " + lastnameList.size());         
    } 
}
```

**SOLVED**
For everyone facing the same problem:
create an if statement BEFORE you're splitting the line. No idea why, but it works.

```
if(!line2.contains(";;")) { 
   then split it

}
```

Comment: Please post your solution as a self-answer, rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [JavaDoc for String.split() that only takes one argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), you'll see that it suppresses trailing empty strings obtained after splitting.

In the case of your semicolon-only lines, splitting them produces only empty strings, therefore everything is an empty trailing string, and split() returns an array of length zero, that is to say for which you cannot access any element since it has none. That's why `splitter2[0]` produces an array index out of bounds exception.

You can adapt as you wish. Either by testing the length of the array rather than checking its potentially non-existing first element. Or by using `line2.split(";", -1)`, which deactivates the suppression of trailing empty strings, thus letting you access all the fields of your lines, whether they may be empty or not.

Comment: Thanks for the underlying theory buddy :) So you would recommend an ifstatement like "if splitter2.length = 0 " ?

Comment: @wutBruh Actually I'd advise the two-parameters split() method, with -1 as second parameter to deactivate the removal of trailing empty string. That behavior is nosy and cause of errors. Your data are usually allowed fields that contain the empty string.

Comment: That -1 does work insanely well. Sorry if I'm a bit rude, but could you explain a little bit easier than "suppression" what it exactly does cuz it doesnt seem to add those trash lines to the arraylists..? Or could you link me to a documentationabout it? (i dont know how the -1 is called:$) Sorry, im really trying to learn these kind of things (im used to only build RSPS's XD..)

Comment: @wutBruh The documentation for the two-parameters split() method is literally right above the documentation for the one-parameter split() method I already linked. As I explained, the one-parameter split() method removes trailing empty strings from its results, and I'd wager this behavior is unwanted and it surprised you. I'd go as far as saying it's unwelcome. Using the two-parameter split() method, with -1 as the second parameter, removes that unwanted behavior: trailing empty strings aren't removed anymore, which is what anyone would have expected by calling split() in the first place.

Comment: thanks man, easy fix for something ive been fixing myself all the time with if statements..

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` is thrown because you call `.equals("")` method 
on `splitter2[0]` element of `splitter2`, but `splitter2.length` returns `0`, which means that `splitter2` has no elements.

The reason for this is that if you run the following code

```
String test = ";;;";    
String[] split = test.split(";"); //split.length is zero
```

you will get an array of `0` elements.

But if you run

```
String test = ";Hello;;";    
String[] split = test.split(";");
```

you will get an array of `2` elements: the first element is an empty string, the second is `"Hello"`.

Comment: Thanks for the underlying theory  :) So your advice would also be making an if statement before the splitting (how I solved it)? Only thing is that I use .contains ";;", but what should i do if a junkline contains only one semicolon ?

Comment: If you are sure that at the end of the file there are always semicolons (no matter how many times are repeated, but at least there is one `;`), then you can test the length of the array with `if(splitter2.length != 0)` instead of using `if(!line2.contains(";;"))`

Comment: no there are neither always semi colons,sometimes its just perfectly fine. But that if statement works then as well i suppose ? I mean it just checks whether the length of the array is not equal to 0 and if the last one is normal it is 4.

Comment: The other answer told me to use .split(";", -1), which seems to work perfectly fine, although i dont properly understand it:P

Comment: Yes, if the last is `"Hello;How;Are;You"`, then you'll get an array of length 4. What I was trying to say is that if you have, for some reason, commas instead of semicolons at the end of the file (let's say 4 commas `",,,,"`), then calling `.split(";")` will return an array of length 1 with only one element `",,,,"`.  Ok, if you see that the other answer is more useful, it is correct that you mark that one :). Maybe you can take a look at the link posted by @kumesana to understand more

Comment: O yes that's no problem :P

Comment: It's not per se that its more useful, i think it does almost the same, but the -1 is shorter.. So ye.. But i really appreciate your help bro :)